# Sorting files into folders using rapidminer based on a classifier results

Tags: rapidminer

I need a help to sort the files that rapidminer classified into the labels (folders), is this task possible in rapidminer or java code that reads the resulting example set?
this is the resulting table

[image]

ie: I just want to split files into folders represent its labels

this is the sample example set

```
    Data: SimpleExampleSet: 15 examples, 31988 regular attributes, 
special attributes = { label = #0: label (polynominal/single_value)/values=[test1] 
metadata_file = #1: metadata_file (polynominal/single_value)/values=[0.txt, 1.txt, 10.txt, 11.txt, 12.txt, 13.txt, 14.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt, 5.txt, 6.txt, 7.txt, 8.txt, 9.txt] 
metadata_path = #2: metadata_path (polynominal/single_value)/values=[D:\Finaltests\test1\0.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\1.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\10.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\11.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\12.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\13.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\14.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\2.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\3.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\4.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\5.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\6.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\7.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\8.txt, D:\Finaltests\test1\9.txt] 
metadata_date = #3: metadata_date (date_time/single_value) 
confidence_sport = #31993: confidence(sport) (real/single_value) 
confidence_places = #31994: confidence(places) (real/single_value) 
prediction = #31992: prediction(label) (binominal/single_value) }
```

thank you.

Comment: Please add the code to your question where you stuck at.

Comment: I have added 2 photos just now, but i don't have code yet, thanks

Comment: I just want to split files into folders represent its labels

Comment: The `Loop Files` and `Log to Data` operators are there to generate fake data as part of my answer below in order that it can standalone. Delete these 2 operators. The output from the `Apply Model` should go directly to the `Generate Attributes` operator. You will have to change the parameters of `Generate Attributes` to match what is in your example set. Set a breakpoint after the `Apply Model` to examine the attributes you have and then work out how to modify the creation of the `old` and `new` attributes.

Comment: the loop file contain the macro used to generate the attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a slightly more complicated process than I said initially so I've included an example below. It assumes Linux and will copy any files from `/tmp/old` to `/tmp/new/A` or `/tmp/new/B`. `A` and `B` is determined by the label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_files" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Loop Files" width="90" x="45" y="34">
    <parameter key="directory" value="/tmp/old"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="provide_macro_as_log_value" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="parent_path" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="macro_name" value="parent_path"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="provide_macro_as_log_value" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="file_name" width="90" x="179" y="136">
        <parameter key="macro_name" value="file_name"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="log" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Log" width="90" x="380" y="34">
        <list key="log">
          <parameter key="parent_path" value="operator.parent_path.value.macro_value"/>
          <parameter key="file_name" value="operator.file_name.value.macro_value"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="parent_path" from_port="through 1" to_op="file_name" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="file_name" from_port="through 1" to_op="Log" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Log" from_port="through 1" to_port="out 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_file object" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="log_to_data" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Log to Data" width="90" x="179" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes (2)" width="90" x="313" y="34">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="label" value="if(rand()&gt;0.5, &quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;)"/>
    </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="313" y="187">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="old" value="parent_path + &quot;/&quot; + file_name"/>
      <parameter key="new" value="&quot;/tmp/new/&quot; + label+ &quot;/&quot; + file_name"/>
    </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_examples" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Loop Examples" width="90" x="514" y="187">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="old" width="90" x="112" y="34">
        <parameter key="macro" value="old"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="old"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="%{example}"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="new" width="90" x="112" y="136">
        <parameter key="macro" value="new"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="new"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="%{example}"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="copy_file" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Copy File" width="90" x="380" y="34">
        <parameter key="source_file" value="%{old}"/>
        <parameter key="new_file" value="%{new}"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_port="example set" to_op="old" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="old" from_port="example set" to_op="new" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="new" from_port="example set" to_op="Copy File" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Copy File" from_port="through 1" to_port="example set"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Loop Files" from_port="out 1" to_op="Log to Data" to_port="through 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Log to Data" from_port="exampleSet" to_op="Generate Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Loop Examples" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

I used `Copy File` to avoid moving files around and causing damage, hopefully you can see how it works.

In summary, if you make attributes with old and new names, you have to use `Loop Examples` to go through each example. Inside this loop operator, you have to extract the values to pass to the `Copy File` operator as macros.

Hope that helps as a basis.

Comment: thank you very much, I imported this process in rapidminer and I'll try to use it in my classification process.

Comment: thank you very much awchisholm. This solved my problem. I appreciate your help http://stackoverflow.com/users/576860/awchisholm

Comment: sir i discoverd that you used the rand() function which give random number but instead i need to use the predection lable value or just i need to know the predected lable name and put it instead

Comment: I created a simulated label using rand() - you would need to remove that part and simply use the label you have.

Comment: could you tel me how to select prediction label from the data set, please.

Comment: In general, you should post some representative data because it is impossible to propose changes without knowing what you have. In general, you only need the last two operators. The `Generate Attributes` operator creates `from` and `to` attributes and assumes there are existing attributes called `parent_path`, `file_name` and `label`. Make your example set matches and all will be well.

Comment: How to get prediction(label) from the example set (output) in rapidminer as attribute?

Comment: The first png file you posted which shows your data has it already.

Comment: yes it is exist in data but how to get it as attribute?does loop label help?or aggregation?

Comment: Terminology: An example set is a collection of examples that make the data. An example is a single row within an example set. An attribute is a column within the example set. You already have the data as an example set and I can see attributes with names like prediction(label).

Comment: yes but i am facing a problem with rapid miner: it didn't recognize an attribute called prediction or prediction lable and the process faild.

Comment: my problem is what i need to write in the function expression in order to represent the prediction(label)?I mean how to call attributes in the function expression? this expression didn't work:` parent_path + "/" +"/new/" +prediction_label+ "/" + file_name`

Comment: Use square brackets around the names of the attributes and be sure to use the exact names of the attributes. For reference, the `Generate Attributes` operator does a lot of the work for you. If you click on `function descriptions` you will see a small calculator-like icon to the right of `function expressions`.  Once in this, you can select `Special Attributes` and you will see the exact names of the prediction attributes. Double clicking on the special attribute will cause it to be copied into the expression with square brackets if they are needed.

Comment: I needed to join the example set and loop file paths macro  in one set in order to connect it to generate attribute